# PDO and Escaping Input: Is this the safest way?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, sql-injection

I wanting to check myself before I go live.  I read so many different things on the internet but I want to know if this will absolutely protect my code for SQL Injection.  If not, what do I need to add or take away?

```
$idtoapprove = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['idtoapprove']);

$getcity = $conn->prepare('SELECT city, state FROM needs WHERE ID=:idtoapprove');
$getcity->bindParam(':idtoapprove', $idtoapprove);
$getcity->execute();

$cityrow = $getcity->fetch();
$needcity = $cityrow['city'];
$needstate = $cityrow['state'];

echo "$needcity, $needstate";
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No need for `mysql_real_escape_string` here, actually, it's flat-out wrong (it's from a different, deprecated database library) and can damage your data. (Also, it would be ineffective here anyway - `mysql_real_escape_string()` is for escaping strings, it is useless for integers.)

The PDO prepared statement is enough.

Comment: You can even check if you really receive an ID, so INT > 0.

Comment: Just to explain further, `mysql_real_escape_string` will not work properly without an active database connection via the `ext/mysql` API which OP is unlikely to have.  Using it would also escape the data twice.